# key.code = 37 and key.code = 39 don't work

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I'm trying to move a canon left and right depending on which arrow (left or right) the user is pressing. This is my code:

```
size(400, 400, P2D);

//Constructor canon
var Canon = function(canonX, canonY, W){
fill(0, 0, 0);

    this.canonX = canonX;
    this.canonY = canonY;
    this.W = W;
};

//CANON MOVELEFT
Canon.prototype.moveLeft = function(){
    this.canonX -= 5;
};
Canon.prototype.moveRight = function(){
    this.canonX += 5;
};

//DRAW CANON
Canon.prototype.drawCanon = function(){
    quad(this.canonX - this.W/5, this.canonY + this.W * 2, this.canonX + 4/5 * this.W, 
this.canonY + 2 * this.W, this.canonX + 3 * this.W/5, this.canonY, this.canonX, this.canonY);
    ellipse(this.canonX + this.W/10 * 3, this.canonY + 2 * this.W, this.W, this.W/ 5 * 3);
    //wheels
    fill(138, 109, 23);
    ellipse(this.canonX - this.W/50 * 12, this.canonY + this.W/50 * 102, this.W/5 * 2, this.W/5 * 6);
    ellipse(this.canonX + this.W/50 * 42, this.canonY + this.W/50 * 102, this.W/5 * 2, this.W/5 * 6);
```

};

```
var canon = new Canon(199, 200, 50);
draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    if(keyIsPressed && key.code === 37){
        canon.moveLeft();
    }
    else if(keyIsPressed && key.code === 39){
        canon.moveRight();
    }
    canon.drawCanon();

};
```

I tryed using e keyCode of 32 (for space) for the condition of both functions moveLeft() and moveRight(). But not with the keyCode of left and right arrow...
Could anybody help me?

Comment: What is `keyIsPressed` & `key`.

Comment: @brk I think it's part of what Processing introduces to the environment.

Comment: How is it called, where are the variables defined? Did you inspect what is in it? `console.log(keyIsPressed, key.code, key)`

Comment: I think you mean `keyCode` instead of `key.code`?

Comment: There are too many issues in this question to get a clear answer

Comment: I replaced key.code by keyCode

It works only while pushing up and then once left or right and keep pushing up. How can that be? And how makes it works only with pushing left and right arrows?

Comment: You're going to need to narrow your problem down to a simpler example. Please post a [mcve] that shows exactly the problem. note that this should not be your full project, but it should be enough code for us to copy and paste to see the problem ourselves.

Comment: Also please note that Processing.js was discontinued in December 2018 - if you're starting a new project, please have a look at https://p5js.org instead.